# How can I express my dismissal from public service in my academic resume?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv

I'm planning to apply to a number of university (public policy) programs in US and I do not know how to express my dismissal from public service following the political turmoil in Turkey. I was dismissed with a decree law, no charges, without being questioned like tens of thousands. How can I state this situation?
Also, how can I include the gap resulted after dismissal?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly why you want to express in the CV?  I would assume that one would just say that one worked a certain period (e.g. 2010 - 2017) and that's it.

Comment: @Buffy The question specifies "in US".

Comment: [Here's an example of how a political dissident can incorporate problems with authorities into their CV](https://physics.cornell.edu/sites/people/files/Orlov%20webpage%20updates%20Sept.%202018.pdf) (PDF link).

Answer (score 6):

I think that under the circumstances you can just tell it truthfully and completely. The recent political turmoil in Turkey was widely reported here, and I think most people would both understand and sympathize with it.

You might also point to the fact that you weren't alone and that the dismissals had nothing to do with the competence of those dismissed. There are plenty of news stories that could be noted.

We aren't perfect here, but so far, our political institutions are holding up.

Answer (score 1):

For positions of this type, I would include 2-3 bullets on the CV describing your work/accomplishments. In one of those bullets, you would say something about the circumstances of the position ending (in this particular case). As @Buffy says, US academics are broadly familiar with the circumstances.

It might also be something interesting to work into your Statement of Interest. Including the story may be appropriate if it is relevant to your reasons for pursuing the degree and plans after degree completion.